# How to format numbers for minimal string length

Tags: r, format, printf

For graphical annotations with tight space constraints, I would like to format numbers in a way that minimizes each number's representation string length. For example, the powers of 10 should be formatted like this:

- 1e-4
- 1e-3
- 0.01
- 0.1
- 1
- 10
- 100
- 1e3
- 1e4

`as.character` seems to do almost this, but unfortunately it puts a redundant leading zero in single-digit exponents, and it inserts a redundant '+' before positive exponents.

```
> as.character(10^(-5:5))
 [1] "1e-05" "1e-04" "0.001" "0.01"  "0.1"   "1"     "10"    "100"   "1000"  "10000" "1e+05"
```

So instead of 1e5, for example, we get 1e+05, which is almost double in length.

Comment: Does `formatC()` help?

Comment: If there is a way to make `formatC()` do this, I can't figure out how.

Comment: From `?formatC`: The rendering of scientific format is platform-dependent: some systems use n.ddde+nnn or n.dddenn rather than n.ddde+nn.

Comment: `sprintf("%.2E", n)` will force scientific notation with to 3 significant figures.  If you want to [avoid regex](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2008/06/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems.html) you could develop a function to apply sprintf conditionally to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a `regex` to remove the unwanted characters...

```
gsub( "\\+|(?<=\\+|\\-)0" , "" , 10^(-5:5) , perl = TRUE )
#[1] "1e-5"  "1e-4"  "0.001" "0.01"  "0.1"   "1"     "10"    "100"   "1000" 
#[10] "10000" "1e5"
```

- `\\+` removes the `+`
- `(?<=...)0` is a zero-width look-behind assertion that removes `0` as long as it is preceeded by whatever is in `...`, in this case `\\+|\\-` which is either `+` or `-`

The `|` separator chains the expressions. The `""` in the second argument of `gsub` replaces matches with nothing.

EDIT: Building on ideas raised in the discussion, here is a ready-to-go solution:

```
formatBrief <- function(x){
    options(scipen=-5)
    sci <- gsub( "(?<=e)\\+?0*|(?<=e-)0*" , "" , x , perl=TRUE)
    options(scipen=5)
    fp <- as.character(x)
    options(scipen=0)
    return (ifelse(nchar(sci)<nchar(fp),sci,fp))
}

> formatBrief(10^(-5:5))
 [1] "1e-5" "1e-4" "1e-3" "0.01" "0.1"  "1"    "10"   "100"  "1e3"  "1e4"  "1e5"
```

Comment: The first two are not accurate

Comment: Great idea! Due to @James's comment about platform dependence I'll go with `(?<=e)\\+?0*|(?<=e-)0*`.

Comment: @tennenrishin good stuff. I don't think you need the `*`'s though.

Comment: Without the `*`'s, the regex won't fully work on cases like '1e+10' and '1e+005'.

Comment: It's a pity this answer doesn't give the shortest representation of numbers like 0.001 and 1000.

Comment: @tennenrishin for that you need to play around with `options( scipen )`, I believe it you set `options( scipen = 0 )` or `options( scipen = -1 )` you will get close to what you want... BUT due to the way R prints `1e3` as `1e+03` for instance you won't get it exactly in one function. You'd have to do some extra processing for that.